# How to load unreferenced libraries which might be used during runtime in Dart Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
Error Stack:
LibraryHelper: Library package:gems_hepatobiliary/constants.dart is not loaded. This can happen for unreferenced libraries
```

While running a project? These constants in the library are used on HomePage/First Page and the above error comes, while clearly other pages are using this library...Any solution...?

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.588], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.10)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.65.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: had the same issue, it seems related to hot-reload keeping the reference in memory. hard restart solved

Comment: Can you prepare or get link on this app example? Maybe do you have public git repository?

Comment: @bdthombre do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to be false positive if the package mentioned is indeed used in the project. A similar issue has been reported on this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96488). While the error reports that the library is unused, the class used seems to still work as expected. If you're able to provide a minimal repro, it'll be helpful if you can submit an issue ticket [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues).